# Missing administrator options Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

I'm running Lubuntu and posts say that you can add drivers by using System > Administration > Hardware/Additional Drivers. There is no such menu choice.

I have system tools or preferences. Neither has the administration option.

Where can I find the additional drivers options in Lubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It's in Menu -> Preference -> Software & Updates in 13.10.

Though I never use that option anymore.  I've had problems with "additional drivers" because it doesn't resolve dependencies properly

Now I just find the name for the package it would install and install it myself using the terminal or synaptic.